# CSS: How do I get rid of some inexplicable space/padding?

Tags: html, css

In this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trusktr/g5sa5/

you see a white spacing between each row of images. How in the world do you get rid of it

Comment: it might have something to do with improper nesting: `<div><a><div></div></a></div>`

Comment: can you create a dummy in http://jsfiddle.net/ or http://jsbin.com/ for future searcher's as example :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are at least two solutions for this. Just add one of the following lines to your `.box_thumb_img`-style:

```
vertical-align: bottom;
```

or

```
display: block;
```

Explanation: By default, browsers treat images as inline-elements. It puts the image at the same height as the baseline (see image below) of your the text (yes, on your page there is no text, but there *could be* some). The space below the images is the space a text would use under its baseline to display characters like g p or q.

To get rid of this, just set the vertical align to the bottom of the text (my fist solution), or don't let the images be inline-elements (my second solution).

[image]

Comment: i added another solution, one of them should work cross-browser.

Comment: Thanks! So how does vertical-align work here? Also, i guess that since the img is inside the a tag that it treats it as inline, otherwise it'd normally be block, right?

Comment: Diagrams make things understandable-like.

Comment: I was trying to resolve this issue for a long time. Great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This one's easy ;)

Images are inline which mean they make use of line-height. You can get around this like so:

```
img{ display: block; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are setting the height on the img, you can set the height of the box too.
In your stylesheet, add `height: 134px;` in `.box`

Answer (score 0):

add this css to your divs containing the images

```
div.classname {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
}
```

UPDATE :

after more review of your site try this

```
.box_thumb_img {
   height: 137px;

}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I've tried everything I can think of. even `* {margin:0; padding:0;}`. It just won't go away. Any other ideas?

Comment: `<div>` elements have no margin or padding by default. This doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could always give it a negative margin. This works, tested on firebug.

```
.box {
    float: left;
    margin: -3px 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: @trusktr it moves up the position of the DIV in the flow of the document. Just like you add margin to add space, you can use it take it away as well. It's just a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to fix the spacing between the lines of text?

Comment: @trusktr I had a look at it, I just dabble in CSS so couldn't find a fix. However, the problem did go away when you increase the font to 13px :)

Comment: yeah I noticed that too. I guess there's a threshold or something so smaller text cant have smaller line-height.

Answer (score 0):

All of your images are 200x134px, so make the containing .box div adhere to those dimensions:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 134px;
}
```

This worked perfectly for me in Chrome.  If you have other issues, then as other posters have noted, your mark-up may not be well-formed.  Check and correct any HTML issues before making further CSS changes.

For your second issue, try adding

```
display: block;
padding: 2px;
```

to your .box_desc_title selector.

Comment: Hey thanks paul. I tried the suggestion you gave for the second part, but that changes the way the box is outlined (a square instead of "highlighting")

Comment: Ah, sorry I thought that was what you wanted.  The question originally said "Also, how do I get rid of the space between each line of the text that is over the images?".  To get the effect you're after, each word will probably have to be in a separate span.

Comment: Actually i found the solution: you have to apply line-height to the parent container of the span. Wierd huh!

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a reset CSS? Try looking at the [Meyer Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
That usually gets rid of any odd bugs like that.

Comment: a reset-css wouldn't fix this: it's intended behaviour to alingn inline-elements at the text-baseline (for more information take a look at my answer).